# i was trying to create a desktop assistant using python but whenever i speak something it shows an error

Tags: python, audio, artificial-intelligence, voice-recognition

FOR EG (I SAY ="Hello bro")
The error-- "'hello' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
or even if i say anything else it displays the 1st word of the sentence and prints(is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.)

I was expecting for now that whatever i say it should repeat that and (though it is detecting and displaying what i said but not sepaking the thing)
AND HERE IS THE CODE BELOW=====

```
import win32com.client as wincom
import speech_recognition as sr
import os

speak = wincom.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")

def say(text):
    os.system(f"{text}")

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with  sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
            print(f"User said: {query}")
            return query
        except Exception as e:
            return "Some Error Occurred. Sorry from Jarvis"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('PyCharm')
    speak.Speak("Hello I am Jarvis AI,how may I help you")
    while True:
        print("Listening.....")
        text = takeCommand()
        say(text)
```

Comment: And what exactly is `os.system(f"{text}")` supposed to do? That runs the string in the command line. Did you mean to use `print()`?

Comment: Thanx bro but one more issue popped up that when the exception occurs it should say it also but it is only returning the eception statement                                                  except Exception as e:
            return "Some Error Occurred. Sorry from Jarvis"
        speak.Speak("Some Error Occurred. Sorry from Jarvis")

Comment: It should be the exact same as return without an exception being raised. What exactly is going wrong?